# Scipy fitting polynomial model to some data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I do try to find an appropriate function for the permeability of cells under varying conditions. If I assume constant permeability, I can fit it to the experimental data and use Sklearns `PolynomialFeatures` together with a `LinearModel` (As explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406975/polynomial-regression-using-python)) in order to determine a correlation between the conditions and the permeability. However, the permeability is not constant and now I try to fit my model with the permeability as a function of the process conditions. The `PolynomialFeature` module of sklearn is quite nice to use.

Is there an equivalent function within scipy or numpy which allows me to create a polynomial model (including interaction terms e.g. `a*x[0]*x[1]` etc.) of varying order without writing the whole function by hand ?

The standard polynomial class in numpy seems not to support interaction terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of such a function that does exactly what you need, but you can achieve it using a combination of `itertools` and `numpy`.

If you have `n_features` predictor variables, you essentially must generate all vectors of length `n_features` whose entries are non-negative integers and sum to the specified order. Each new feature column is the component-wise power using these vectors who sum to a given order.

For example, if `order = 3` and `n_features = 2`, one of the new features will be the old features raise to the respective powers, `[2,1]`. I've written some code below for arbitrary order and number of features. I've modified the generation of vectors who sum to `order` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28969798/1430829).

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import binom 

def polynomial_features_with_cross_terms(X, order):
    """
    X: numpy ndarray
        Matrix of shape, `(n_samples, n_features)`, to be transformed.
    order: integer, default 2
        Order of polynomial features to be computed. 

    returns: T, powers.
        `T` is a matrix of shape,  `(n_samples, n_poly_features)`.
        Note that `n_poly_features` is equal to:

           `n_features+order-1` Choose `n_features-1`

        See: https://en.wikipedia.org\
        /wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29#Theorem_two

        `powers` is a matrix of shape, `(n_features, n_poly_features)`.
        Each column specifies the power by row of the respective feature, 
        in the respective column of `T`.
    """
    n_samples, n_features = X.shape
    n_poly_features = int(binom(n_features+order-1, n_features-1))
    powers = np.zeros((n_features, n_poly_features))
    T = np.zeros((n_samples, n_poly_features), dtype=X.dtype)

    combos = itertools.combinations(range(n_features+order-1), n_features-1)
    for i,c in enumerate(combos):
        powers[:,i] = np.array([
            b-a-1 for a,b in zip((-1,)+c, c+(n_features+order-1,))
        ])

        T[:,i] = np.prod(np.power(X, powers[:,i]), axis=1)

    return T, powers
```

Here's some example usage:

```
>>> X = np.arange(-5,5).reshape(5,2)
>>> T,p = polynomial_features_with_cross_terms(X, order=3)
>>> print X
[[-5 -4]
 [-3 -2]
 [-1  0]
 [ 1  2]
 [ 3  4]]
>>> print p
[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
 [ 3.  2.  1.  0.]]
>>> print T
[[ -64  -80 -100 -125]
 [  -8  -12  -18  -27]
 [   0    0    0   -1]
 [   8    4    2    1]
 [  64   48   36   27]]
```

Finally, I should mention that the [SVM polynomial kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_kernel) achieves exactly this effect without explicitly computing the polynomial map. There are of course pro's and con's to this, but I figured I should mentioned it for you to consider if you have not, yet.