# How to make a polynomial regression with sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, polynomials, non-linear-regression

I have some data that doesn't fit a linear regression:

[image]

In fact should fit a quadratic function 'exactly':

```
P = R*I**2
```

I'm making this:

```
model = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()

X = alambres[alambre]['mediciones'][x].reshape(-1, 1)
Y = alambres[alambre]['mediciones'][y].reshape(-1, 1)
model.fit(X,Y)
```

Is there any chance to solve it by doing something like:

```
model.fit([X,X**2],Y)
```

Comment: An example of how to use `scikit-learn` with polynomial features can be found here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#polynomial-regression-extending-linear-models-with-basis-functions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [polynomial regression using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406975/polynomial-regression-using-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use numpy's [polyfit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html).

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
X = np.linspace(0, 100, 50)
Y = 23.24 + 2.2*X + 0.24*(X**2) + 10*np.random.randn(50) #added some noise
coefs = np.polyfit(X, Y, 2)
print(coefs)
p = np.poly1d(coefs)
plt.plot(X, Y, "bo", markersize= 2)
plt.plot(X, p(X), "r-") #p(X) evaluates the polynomial at X
plt.show()
```

Out:

```
[  0.24052058   2.1426103   25.59437789]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that the title asks for a sklearn solution. I'll leave this as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Use PolynomialFeatures.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

x = np.array([[1,],[2,],[3,]])
X = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2).fit_transform(x)
X
```

Output:

```
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 2., 4.],
       [1., 3., 9.]])
```

Comment: You need to combine the polynomial feature generation with a linear regression to perform polynomial regression in SKLearn.