# Python: polynomial fit of a scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, regression

My `dataframe` has two colums, say `x` and `y`. The graph below shows the `scatter plot` of `x` and `y`.

Based on the scatter plot, I make a linear fitting using the following code which results in the blue straight line in the following image.

[image]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
ax.scatter(df['x'], df['y'])
b, m = polyfit(df['x'], df['y'], 1)
ax.plot(df['x'], b + m * df['x'], 'blue', linewidth=1)
```

Now, I want to make another fitting curve, maybe polynomial, of the scatter plot. The wanted result is something like the red curve in the above image. I tried using the following from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37110879/which-is-the-simplest-way-to-make-a-polynomial-regression-with-sklearn).

```
coefs = np.polyfit(df['x'], df['y'], 2)
p = np.poly1d(coefs)
plt.plot(df['x'], df['y'], "bo", markersize= 2)
plt.plot(df['x'], p(df['x']), "r-")
```

But the result is incorrect for my data as shown below.
[image]
How should I proceed?
**Edit**: The data is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1efdDhZamnVoChGPU_57UkN_SufyrvMbc/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: fit is created based on data spread [few points outside the main grouping adding miscalculations]. You can delete all points outside the mainstream data, and try again. Or you can use weights to apply to the y-coordinates of the sample points

Comment: @Zaraki Kenpachi. I don't mind to include outliers with risk. The problem is, as you can see, the curve is not single, but multiple lines back and forth.

Comment: post link to you data, then i try to find solution

Comment: please see Edit

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998607/large-dataset-polynomial-fitting-using-numpy

Comment: The problem lies in the sorting, check the answer below. For linear fit, you don't see it because going back and forth among the points on a straight line is still a straight line path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the link posted by Zaraki Kenpachi, try adding `df = df.sort_values(by='x')` before your existing fitting and plotting code.