# How to perform a polynomial regression from N-dimensions set of samples in Python?

Tags: python, math, statistics, regression, probability

Here is the **context of my problem**: I have data samples from measurements. I'm reccording N properties. From those data I would like to perform a sensitivity analysis to focus my study on significant parameters. If I use the sobol method for example, I need to transform my data into a "model" to manipulate it (estimation from regression).

As a result, here is **my question**: do you know a method (or a toolbox if it exists) to perform a N-dimensions polynomial/spline regression (not linear), in Python language?

I heard something about a catmull-rom method, but I don't understand how to apply it.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate. Look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406975/polynomial-regression-using-python

Comment: I am afraid, this question is off topic for SO. [Please see here under #4.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Having said that, explore scipy.interpolate and numpy.polyfit.

Comment: It's not a duplicate because the mentionned topic is only concerning 2 dimensions, not N.

Comment: And it's not an issue under #4 because scipy.interpolate is doing linear after 2D, and I don't want linear. => It must be understood "in python, how to switch from 2D to ND".